# He bought two notebooks for her

Tags: grammar

1. He bought two books for her.
2. He bought the laptop for his nephew.
3. He bought the bananas for his sons.

---

Thank you for your help. This question is about 'for her', 'for his nephew', and 'for his son'. They are prepositional phrases. By the way, what is the part of speech of each? Are they adverbial phrases or adjective phrases?

Comment: "They are prepositional phrases." That's a statement. What's your question about prepositional phrases? Also, the last part of your question is a *different* question that's unrelated. Or it seems to be . . .

Comment: The prepositional phrases can be considered to modify either the verb or the object.  In these simple examples (without context to the contrary) you get the same meaning either way.

Comment: They're called _Benefactive_ phrases because they describe the benificiary of the action. This may include transfer of possession, as in the examples with _bought_, which means that they can undergo the Dative Alternation, producing _He bought her two books, He bought his nephew the laptop, He bought his sons the bananas,_ all grammatical. However, if it doesn't involve transfer, Dative is blocked -- _I fixed the car for him_ but not *_I fixed him the car._

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the concept of **part of speech** and the concept of **grammatical function.**

Part of speech, also called **lexical category,** is something that refers to individual words. So *for* is a preposition, *her* and *his* are pronouns, and *nephew* and *sons* are nouns.

What we can ask about prepositional phrases (PPs) is what kind of *grammatical function* they perform in the sentence, for they can perform many different kinds of functions ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 646):

> **5.3 Functions of PPs**
>
> We have already seen from the account of the internal structure of PPs that one PP can  function within a larger one, as head, complement, or modifier:
>
> [33]  i  *Sue was still [**at odds** with her parents] on this issue.*                     [head in PP]
>  
>            ii  *She lives [just down the street **from Kim's**].*                        [complement in PP] 
>           iii  *I'm [down here **by the back door**].*                                              [modifier in PP]
>
> For the most part, however, PPs function in other constructions, as in:
>
> [34]    i  *I gave the key **to Sue.***                                            } 
>  
>              ii  *She put the key **in her bag.***                                 }                     [complement in clause]
>  
>             iii  *They are **under the table.***                                 }
>  
>             iv  *She had slept **in the attic.***                                                                   [adjunct in clause]
>  
>              v  *Where's [the key **to the safe**]?*                                                         [complement in NP]
>  
>             vi  *They bought [a house **with a flat roof**].*                                            [ modifier in NP]
>  
>            vii  *There are now [fewer **than a hundred**] seats left.*                   [complement in DP]
>  
>           viii  *[Only one **in twenty**] candidates were shortlisted.*                          [modifier in DP]
>  
>             ix  *They are still [ very keen **on surfing**].*                                       [complement in AdjP]
>              x  *He was [ tired **to the point of exhaustion**].*                               [ modifier in AdjP ]
>             xi  *He likes to do things [differently **from everyone else**].*      [complement in AdvP]
>  
>            xii  *I'll be seeing her [later **in the week**].*                                                [modifier in AdvP]

This is a bit how noun phrases (NPs) can perform any of the following functions: the subject of a clause, the object of a transitive verb, the predicative complement of a copula, etc.

In all of your examples, the PPs are **complements in the structure of the clause.** There are two key points in that statement: that they are **complements** as opposed to **adjuncts,** and that they perform this function at the level of the **clause,** and not, say, at the level of an NP.

Let me explain the second point first. What I am saying is that one should not think of

[1] *He bought two books for her.*

as *he bought X*, where X is an NP, namely *two books for her.* If that were so, the PP *for her* would function as a post-head modifier in the noun phrase. PPs do sometimes have that function, e.g. in the following NP: *the key **to the safe.*** However, that's not the role that the PP has in [1]. One way to see that is to notice that *for her* can be **fronted**: *for her, he bought two books*; notice that fronting is not possible in *the key to the safe*: *he found the key to the safe* cannot be restated as **to the safe, he found the key.* Moreover, we notice that the choice of the preposition in [1] is licensed by the verb, not the noun. So it would be *he gave two books **to** her,* not *for her.* In contrast, *the key to the safe* keeps functioning as a unit no matter what verb we use: *I've made/borrowed/lent/destroyed/etc. the key to the safe.*

However, as sumelic pointed out in comments to this answer, it is possible to modify [1] a bit so that the NP intepretation becomes much more likely. Here is one way:

[1'] *All he bought was two books for her.*

Back to [1]: the fact that the preposition is licensed is what makes the PP a complement as opposed to an adjunct (CGEL, pp. 219-220).

Some sources use the term [**adverbial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial) so that it includes a PP that is either a complement or adjunct in the structure of a clause. This should not be confused with the concept of an adverb phrase, which is always [headed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) by an adverb (and there are no adverbs in [1]). Similarly, an adjective phrase is always headed by an adjective, and there are no adjectives in [1].

Another thing to notice is that [1] alternates with a ditransitive construction:

[2] *He bought her two books.*

In [2], *her* is an **indirect object.** As CGEL says (p. 308),

> The indirect object generally expresses arguments with the semantic role of recipient or beneficiary, and these arguments are also commonly expressed by PPs headed by *to* and *for* respectively.

Since in [1] the pronoun *her* is related to the verb indirectly via a preposition, it is referred to as an **oblique.**

Comment: Why isn't it ambiguous?

Comment: @sumelic I thought about it, but I think that reading is far less likely. I think it is very hard to conceptualize [1] so that the possibility of fronting disappears.

Comment: I'd guess you're right about the frequency, but the interpretation with a noun phrase "two books for her" seems technically possible to me, and not all that strained. I find it a bit difficult to think of ways to force this interpretation. What about something like "All that he bought was two books for her"?

Comment: @sumelic That's very nice! I think in this case indeed the NP interpretation is indeed more likely, although the fronted version is still viable: *For her, all that he bought was two books.* I'll include this in the text.

Comment: @sumelic It would be nice to come up with parallel sentences that show that *for* no longer needs to be licensed by the verb in that sentence.